# What's the difference of j__objc_msgSend and objc_msgSend?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reverse-engineering, ida

I'm surprised that searching **j__objc_msgSend** returns 0 result on stackoverflow, and Google doesn't seem to know it well either. According to it's [disassembly](http://d.pr/i/49IE), j__objc_msgSend only calls objc_msgSend, then why do we need j__objc_msgSend when we have objc_msgSend already? And in general, what's the difference of j__objc_msgSend and objc_msgSend?

And in this [screenshot](http://d.pr/i/7cS8) specifically, what's the difference of the right most branch ending with "End of function", and the left most branch ending without "End of function"? Does it have something to do with **j__objc_msgSend**?

Comment: There is no reference for j__objc_msgSend function in [Apple's latest public version of gcc](http://www.opensource.apple.com/tarballs/gcc/gcc-4061.tar.gz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is ARM RISC code, and the preferred programming mode for ARM is *relative* -- don't use absolute addresses, always use "IP+/-offset". Here, the called address was out of range for a direct call or jump, and the compiler used the nearest he could find. It adds an extra jump (or more than 1!) but it's position-independent. (*)

   The compiler cannot construct a jump to the target address with a simple instruction, because you cannot immediately load every possible 2^32 number with RISC assembly.
2. If the routine `objc_msgSend` returns of its own, then this is equivalent to `call objc_msgSend; return` -- only shorter. Both forms do a single 'return', from the point of view of the current function.

---

(*) You can see in the disassembly screenshot (?? why not text?) that R12 gets loaded with the *difference* between the target and the current address. This difference is calculated by the compiler; it does *not* appear as a subtraction in the original binary, that's IDA's work. Then the difference is added to the current address -- whatever this is! The immediate value `objc_msgSend - 0x1AE030` uses a small enough amount of bits to be loaded into R12 in a single instruction (an ARM RISC 'feature' you ought to be familiar with).

In case you are wondering about the `j__label` syntax: that's just IDA, telling you this is a direct jump to a known label. Presumably, if your code is long enough, you might find the distance to *this* label is too big again, and so you might find `j__j__objc_msgSend`.